# Make more arrays based on user value

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on a type of lottery script where the user can enter an amount of "rows" he wants on his coupon. These arrays are then filled with random numbers within a range, so that they are different.
My question is how I can make more arrays based on a users input. 
Let's say he wants 5 rows, then the code is supposed to make 5 arrays containing random numbers, but instead of me duping code, I'd like this process to happen in some loop or so.

Thanks.

Comment: Use an array of arrays? If you want a table using a 2D array seems to be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a multi-dimensional array. Let's say a row is 20 numbers and the user chose 5 rows:

```
int numRows = 5;  // Based on user input
int[,] coupon = new int[numRows, 20];
```

Now you can loop through each row and show the numbers (after you add them of course):

```
for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 20; ++column)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0},{1} - {2}", row, column, coupon[row, column]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seem to be what I am needing.
Would something like this work?
https://pastebin.com/HDJdKY7h

Comment: It's very hard to read like that, but it looks like you're looping through `rowAmount` in the outer and the inner loop. The outer loop should iterate through the rows and the inner loop should iterate through the columns.

Comment: Just made it into  a pastebin, couldn't get the codething to work :/

Comment: Ah, I see. I changed the inner one to the columns (amout of numbers in each row)

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks a lot!
https://gyazo.com/2a0654b8d40665fa6eb4ed141ab268b5?token=75dcdb310f6aab7c8185b2ff66cb24d2